# How to use geoserver to publish 3D services?

Tags: geoserver

How to use geoserver to publish 3D services? 2.24.0 version

I am a newcomer and am currently researching geoserver. I don't know how to publish 3D services.

I am seeking everyone's help on how to publish 3D services on GeoServer. Thank you first. For example, some reference articles or your experience, thank you

Comment: What sort of 3D services are you interested in?